# Issue while Fetching data's from DB(DB2) using UDP Value

Tags: udp, db2, odbc, dsn

I Couldn't Fetch (Select) the data from DB using UDP Value, whereas I'm able to Insert data in DB.

**Note** Passing DSN through UDP Value

**Query** 
`SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.Result.data[] = PASSTHRU('SELECT EMPID,NAME FROM Database.{UDPvalue}.{Schema_name}.{Table_name}');`

Comment: Not enough information. Give the exception details, or describe what actually happens.

Comment: @mao Thanks for your Feedback, Actually I'm trying to hit the DB using DSN through UDP Value and not by specifying in Compute Node Properties.Whereas i can able to insert the data's in DB using UDP Value  but i couldn't Fetch(select) the data.                                  **EXCEPTION**                                                                    DatabaseException
             Text:CHARACTER:[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified.

Comment: That exception: "Data source name not found and no default driver specified" tells enough . Your problem is not that you cannot fetch, the problem is that the code performing the fetch is not properly configured to connect to the database.